# UTF-8 encoding not set for Spring integration tests running with Maven on Windows

Tags: java, spring, maven, utf-8, integration-testing

Since I updated my Windows 10 and installed new OpenJDK 11.0.4 my Spring integration tests are not running anymore in the Maven context. Starting it within Eclipse is fine and still working but running it with mvn clean install it is not working aynmore with the error:

```
   18:01:01.340 ERROR [main]:[org.springframework.boot.context.FileEncodingApplicationListener] System property 'file.encoding' is currently 'Cp1252'. It should be 'UTF-8' (as defined in 'spring.mandatoryFileEncoding').
18:01:01.341 ERROR [main]:[org.springframework.boot.context.FileEncodingApplicationListener] Environment variable LANG is 'null'. You could use a locale setting that matches encoding='UTF-8'.
18:01:01.341 ERROR [main]:[org.springframework.boot.context.FileEncodingApplicationListener] Environment variable LC_ALL is 'null'. You could use a locale setting that matches encoding='UTF-8'.
18:01:01.344 ERROR [main]:[org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Java Virtual Machine has not been configured to use the desired default character encoding (UTF-8).
    at org.springframework.boot.context.FileEncodingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(FileEncodingApplicationListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.FileEncodingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(FileEncodingApplicationListener.java:47)
```

I have set UTF-8 encoding everywhere I was able to set.

1. In the application-test.properties

> ```
> file.encoding=UTF-8
> spring.mandatoryFileEncoding=UTF-8
> spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
> spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
> ```

2. in the maven properties and plugin configurations:

```
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>



  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>Java 11</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
      </properties>
      <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${build-version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <release>${java.version}</release>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
          <version>2.4.0-b180830.0438</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ --> <!-- TODO move to stable version when available -->
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
```

3. In the integration tests properties:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(properties = "file.encoding=UTF-8", classes = SEBServer.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
```

4. While starting maven as a VM argument

mvn clean install -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

can anyone tell me where else I can set the encoding? there seems to be as many possible places as stars in the sky but nowhere the right one.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there anywhere that you are setting the encoding property to Cp1252?

Comment: @BillNaylor No. It is also the case that the maven build works on other machines and CI integration systems but not locally on Windows 10 with Open JDK 11.0.4

Comment: This may be a clue, I found this page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#:~:text=Windows%2D1252%20or%20CP%2D1252,character%20encoding%20in%20the%20world.
which is saying that that encoding is used *by default* in legacy Windows Components (?). So maybe there is some way to stop the default?

Comment: The error message seems to suggest that your `system property` is Cp1252, can you change that to UTF-8?

Comment: @BillNaylor I've also set now LANG=en_US.UTF-8 and LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 as suggested in some other posts but still no effect.

Comment: You say this is a Windows environment, have you checked the `environment variables` of the machine what is the value of the `file.encoding` variable? Is there one, if not can you create it with value `UTF-8`?

Comment: @BillNaylor Yes the file.encoding environment variable is set to UTF-8 for the system. The only way so far that works is to explicitly give the attribute as parameter to the mvn command -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8. This works but I've to give it all the time when I work on command line.

Comment: I've looked into this issue a bit, you mention you are using the `maven-surefire-plugin` (though I thought this was for unit tests not integration test). This post: https://github.com/intuit/karate#test-reports suggests that you should include a `systemProperties` child in your configuration. This would have a `<file.encoding>` child with content `UTF-8` (I think). If the issue is you should be using a plugin for integration tests, then `maven-failsafe-plugin`, checkout https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/system-properties.html

Comment: Actually https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html suggests that `systemProperties` are deprecated for the `maven-surefire-plugin` and you should use `systemPropertyVariables` for that too.

Comment: @BillNaylor yes, the systemPropertyVariables did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Shall I write that up as an answer (for other peoples benefit?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the encoding `Cp1252` is used by default in some legacy Windows Components (see: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#:~:text=Windows%2D1252%20or%20CP%2D1252,character%20encoding%20in%20the%20world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#:%7E:text=Windows%2D1252%20or%20CP%2D1252,character%20encoding%20in%20the%20world))
As the OP mentions that the problem (integration/unit tests not running any more) go's away if the parameter `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` is added to the `mvn` invocation, it seems that we need a way to hard code this in the `pom.xml`.
This may be done by including a `systemPropertyVariables` child in the `configuration` element of the unit test plugin `maven-surefire-plugin`. A similar `systemPropertyVariables` child exists for the integration test plugin `maven-failsafe-plugin`.
References: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html
and
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/system-properties.html

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
     <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```